# Proof verification: there is no rational $x$ such that $x^3 = 7$.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that there is no rational $x$ solving $x^3 = 7$. My thought proces sis that I can proceed similarly to the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Here is my attempt.

> Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x^3 = 7$. Write $x = \frac{m}{n}$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \neq 0$, where we can assume, without loss of generality, that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Then
> $$
> x^3 = \frac{m^3}{n^3} = 7,
> $$
> so $m^3 = 7 n^3$. Then $7 \mid m^3$; as $7$ is prime, $7$ divides $m$, so we can write $m = 7k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then
> $$
> m^3 = (7k)^3 = 7n^3,
> $$
> so $7^3 k^3 = 7 n^3$ and hence $7^2 n^3 = n^3$. Then $7 \mid n^3$ and hence $7 \mid n$, contradicting the fact that $m$ and $n$ have no common factors.

How does this look? One possible hole in my proof is that I'm assuming prime factorizations and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which is a result only for positive natural numbers. I could add a line stating that $x > 0$ because, otherwise, $x^3 < 0$, and of course $7$ is positive.

Comment: "One possible hole in my proof is that I'm assuming prime factorizations and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic" -- No.  You are really only assuming (1) the existence of a reduced fraction for $x$ and (2) that $7$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @BrianMoehring How would you define a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$, though? Is it an integer divisible only by itself and $\pm 1$? (I assume a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is also prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what prime numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ are, with a minor correction that it should be $\pm$ itself and $\pm1$. Generally speaking, we define **units** in a ring as the invertible elements; and then **primes** $p$ are those nonunits such as in any factorization $p=ab$ either $a$ or $b$ is a unit. For $\mathbb{Z}$, the units are precisely $\pm1$.

Comment: Typo in final paragraph: "... and hence $7^2n^3 = n^3$." should read "... and hence $7^2k^3 = n^3$."

Comment: It also makes use of the fact that if $p$ is prime and $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$ (and the most straightforward proof I know of uses the fact that the gcd of two numbers is a linear combination of them, which delves into $\mathbb{Z}$ being a PID).  Plus, the cancellativity property of multiplication by a nonzero number, but that's less heavy to prove.

Comment: I feel like making use of elementary properties isn't really making an "assumption." FTA, the fact that $p \mid ab \iff p \mid a \lor p \mid b$, you don't have to re-prove those.